# Hover on li class

Tags: css, hover

I have this code in my custom css theme on opencart. I want to add hover color on it. How can i do that? Thank you

```
.navbar .nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    background-color: #3cbc67; /* for second link bg */
    color: #d61d1d;            /* for first link text color */
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple question regarding CSS color code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758421/simple-question-regarding-css-color-code)

Answer (score 2):

Use the pseudo selector :hover

```css
.navbar .nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: blue;
}
    
.navbar .nav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
   <ul class="nav">
      <li><a>I dont do anything</a></li>
      <li><a>I change color when hover</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .nav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
//styles goes here
}
```

Comment: Please try adding more details on how this code may answer the question. Right now, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I know this was supposed to a comment but my reputation doesn't allow me to add comments.

Comment: That`s why I did not downvote - but you could make it a full-qualified answer by adding more details.

Comment: Thank you Santana and Hassan for your answer!